# How to combine multiple SQL queries

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL and I am trying to figure out how to get multiple queries into the same result of six items.

The queries I want to combine are:

```
SELECT TOP 2 * 
FROM tablename 
WHERE (time >= '20180226 21:00' AND channelname = 'A') 
ORDER BY time ASC 

SELECT TOP 2 * 
FROM tablename 
WHERE (time >= '20180226 21:00' AND channelname = 'B') 
ORDER BY time ASC 

SELECT TOP 2 * 
FROM tablename 
WHERE (time >= '20180226 21:00' AND channelname = 'C') 
ORDER BY time ASC
```

The only thing that changes is the `ChannelName`, and I'm sure there is a way to do this but my syntax skills around SQL are to say the least, limited, I'm stuck.

Comment: Put `union all`in between the queries

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select * from (SELECT TOP 2 * 
FROM   tablename 
WHERE ( time >= '20180226 21:00' 
        AND channelname = 'A' ) ORDER  BY time ASC )t1
UNION ALL 

Select * from (SELECT TOP 2 * 
FROM   tablename 
WHERE ( time >= '20180226 21:00' 
        AND channelname = 'B' ) ORDER  BY time ASC )t2
UNION ALL

Select * from (SELECT TOP 2 * 
FROM   tablename 
WHERE ( time >= '20180226 21:00' 
        AND channelname = 'C' ) 
ORDER  BY time ASC )t3
```